# Looking forward to talk to you or looking forward to talking to you. Which is correct?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I always use *Looking forward to talk to you*. But I kind of have the feeling it is not correct.

Which of the following is the correct way to use?

> Looking forward to talk to you

or

> Looking forward to talking to you.

Comment: Did you intend for one of your two options to have "talk" without "ing"?  As it is, your alternatives are identical.

Comment: @cobaltduck I agree with you, the previous examples were wrongly identical.  I've edited it to make it into more of an actual question.

Comment: Fun fact: when writing an email using Gmail with "Look forward" it suggests "Look forward to speaking with you".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ...looking forward to talking

Is correct. Many students were told by their teacher to not put -ing after to. But, *to* in *..look forward to..* is not an infinitive marker. "Look forward to" is a prepositional phrase and "to" is a **preposition** here. A preposition needs a direct object. A direct object can be a noun or a noun form of verb (gerund).

Answer (score 4):

The structure is either "I look forward to X" or "I am looking forward to X".  Both are idiomatic.  Here "X" represents some *noun*, so you can insert any person, place, or thing.  "Talking" is a [*gerund*](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/gerund.htm), which is the -ing form of a verb used as a noun to represent the *action* of doing that thing.  Other examples:

> I look forward to [having dinner with you tonight].
>
> I look forward to [meeting you for dinner tonight].
>
> I look forward to [eating dinner with you tonight].
>
> I look forward to [seeing you for dinner tonight].
>
> I look forward to [dining with you tonight].

By the way, despite the fact that I use different actions, all of these sentences mean more or less the same thing.  Or I could avoid the gerund entirely and just insert the noun:

> I look forward to [dinner with you tonight].

Similarly any other noun (or noun phrase) works:

> I'm looking forward to the playoff game.
>
> I look forward to my next paycheck.
>
> I look forward to when this election is finally over.
>
> I'm looking forward to Spring.

Comment: To conclude, are you saying "Looking forward to talk to you" is the correct way?

Comment: By itself, "talk" is a verb, not a noun.  If you want to use it as a noun you can say, "I'm looking forward to our *talk*".  Otherwise please read the linked page on gerunds.

Answer (score 0):

**look forward to** requires **-ing** form. In such phrase *to* is a preposition (not an infinitive form), therefore it *must* refer to a noun.

Often, a verb in **-ing** form is used as noun. This is a phrase and you can check its correctness in any English dictionary or grammar book.

In conclusion: **looking forward to *talking* to you** is the correct form.

Comment: Syntactically, it's ***I am** looking forward to X*, where the point is ***X*** has to be a *noun*. This would still be the case with Simple Present *I **look** forward to X*, so it might be misleading for learners if they assume there's some connection between the ***continuous participle*** verb form ***looking*** and the ***gerund noun*** form ***talking***. The "nouniness" of the gerund form can easily be seen in, say, ***Talking** to you **is something** I look forward to.*

Comment: @egcmi To conclude, are you saying "Looking forward to talk to you" is the correct way?